# Meteor.Error not displaying anything

Tags: meteor

I'm validating some form input in a meteor app and trying to use Meteor.Error to throw some information back to the user when the fields fail validation (as is done in microscope).. however, nothing shows on the browser (does throw an error into the console however).

```
  if(!firstN)                                                                                           |e</label>
    {                                                                                                     |      <div class="col-sm-10">
      console.log("No first name given");                                                                 |        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="
      throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'Please provide a First Name');                                         |lname" placeholder = "Required"/>
    }                                                                                                     |      </div>
    if(!lastN)                                                                                            |    </div>
    {                                                                                                     |    <div class="form-group">
      console.log("No last name given");                                                                  |      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</l
      throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'Please provide a Last Name');                                          |abel>
    }                                                                                                     |      <div class="col-sm-10">
    if(!emailAdd)                                                                                         |        <input type="email" class="form-control" id=
    {                                                                                                     |"email" placeholder = "Required"/>
      console.log("No email address given");                                                              |      </div>
      throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'Please provide an Email Address');                                     |    </div>
    }                                                                                                     |    <div class="form-group">
    if(!message)                                                                                          |      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone Nu
    {                                                                                                     |mber</label>
      console.log("No mesage text given");                                                                |      <div class="col-sm-10">
      throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'Please provide a message');                                            |        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="p
    }
```

I'm not sure why I'm not getting anything displayed on the page. I thought it may be because I didn't have the errors meteorite package installed, but did that and nothing has changed.

Any ideas? I am using bootstrap-3 if that matters.

Ta

Peter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to actually catch the error with a `try/catch` block. In your catch block you can display the message to the user. Otherwise, the error will just get logged to the console and JavaScript execution will stop (ever had a program crash on you and display an error window saying "an **uncaught** exception was raised"?). For example, you can do something like:

```
try {
  validateInput();
} catch( e ) {
  Session.set( "errorMessage", e.message );
}
```

And in your template helpers:

```
Template.myForm.errorMessage = function() {
  return Session.get( "errorMessage" );
};
```

And in your template:

```
<template name="myForm">
  <form>
    <p class="error">{{errorMessage}}</p>
    <!-- more form stuff -->
  </form>
</template>
```

Update:

There is another way you can use `Meteor.Error`. If you throw an error from within a method on the server, it will return the error object across to the client to the method callback, and you don't need to use a try/catch block. For example:

```
Meteor.methods({
  foo: function( bar ) {
    if ( bar === "baz" ) {
      return true;
    } else if ( bar === "qux" ) {
      return false;
    } else {
      throw new Meteor.Error( "bah humbug" );
    }
  }
});

if ( Meteor.isClient ) {
  Meteor.call( "foo", function( error, result ) {
    // We didn't provide a `bar` argument, so the method will throw an error.
    // We can handle the error in this callback (no try/catch needed)
  });
}
```

If you look through the Microscope code, you'll notice that they only use `Meteor.Error` from within methods. This is really the main purpose of `Meteor.Error` - Meteor knows how to send this kind of error to the client. If you're throwing an error on the client, you can just use a built in JavaScript `Error`:

```
throw new Error( "message" );
```

Internally, on the server, Meteor uses a `try/catch` block to catch `Meteor.Error`s and return them to a client.

Comment: Thanks for this Cuberto, I am certainly getting uncaught exception. My only issue is that I can't find a catch anywhere in the microscope code from Discover Meteor.. Odd.

Comment: Thank you.. very through... all makes sense now.

Comment: Thank you Cuberto.  Very thorough indeed. Peter